# Can i delete a message in kafka server if it is unconsumed?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have the message id, is it possible for a client to delete a kafka message which is on a topic and is not still consumed by a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is generally not possible (for a client) to delete an individual message out of a Kafka topic.

Removing messages from a Kafka topic is managed through the topic level configuration `cleanup.policy`. According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#topicconfigs):

> A string that is either "delete" or "compact". This string designates the retention policy to use on old log segments. The default policy ("delete") will discard old segments when their retention time or size limit has been reached. The "compact" setting will enable log compaction on the topic.

The "delete" mode is based on a time or byte size limit whereas the "compact" mode ensures that you have at least one message for the same key available in the topic.

As a workaround in your case, I can think of the following:

- enable log compaction for the topic
- ensure that you have defined an individual key for each different message in the topic
- if you plan to delete one particular message, send a message to the topic with the same key and a "null" value. In that case, this message will be eventually deleted through the compaction cleaner.

A detailed explanation on log compaction is given in the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#compaction).

Comment: The use case is to prioritize a message, so if there is a message that needs prioritization client can write some logic to send it on a high priority topic, but then the original message on the normal priority topic should be deleted as well